# SQL server 2012 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Will CDC work with SQL Server Always on Availability groups? Do you need to set up CDC on both/multiples nodes if using Availability Clusters?

Comment: I just searched for "always on" "change data capture" cdc, and got back this as the *first result*:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403414.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CDC will work with SQL Server Always ON availability groups. Check [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403414(v=sql.110).aspx#CDC).

There is already an answer here - [Does Change Data Capture (CDC) work in a SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Failover Cluster Instances setup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43578/does-change-data-capture-cdc-work-in-a-sql-server-2012-alwayson-failover-clust)